# MappingJacksonValue class is missing in [spring-android-rest-template]

Tags: java, android, spring-mvc, spring-android

I have a desktop app. Before, I wrote some utility classes for working with my REST endpoint via **spring-webmvc** RestTemplate dependency. Now I decide to use the same utility classes in my android app.

As you know, in android app you cannot use spring-webmvc because android is not using the same JDK. Therefore I changed my dependency to **spring-android-rest-template** in order to use the RestTemplate class.

Unfortunately, there is a class called: **MappingJacksonValue** which is not available in the **spring-android-rest-template** therefore my utility classes does not resolve and compile successfully.

I wanna get over this problem by a hack method or a solution. Do you have any suggestion for solving this problem ?